# React: How to get results from one component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a search component, which should have an input field and a result list. My problem is how to get the result data to the result component.

This is the input component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { searchData } from '/imports/api/search/methods.js';

export default class Search extends Component {
    handleChange(event) {
        searchData.call(
            { value: event.target.value },
            (error, result) => {
                if (result && result.length > 0) {
                    console.log(result); // <-- Send this results to result component
                }
            }
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder='Search'
            />
        )
    }
}
```

And this should be my result list, which should be shown only if there is any result:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class SearchResult extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    // Show all result elements
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a parent component, containing both `Search` and `SearchResult`, that would hold some internal state.

That way when you get your results inside your `handleChange` method, you can invoke a prop callback to pass the data up to parent, hence calling inside the parent `this.setState()` with the data and then passing that data down to your `SearchResults` with props.

This technique is generally known as [lifting the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

An example of that container could be:

```
class SearchContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
    this.handleResultChange = this.handleResultChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleResultChange(data) {
    this.setState({
      data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search onDataFetched={this.handleResultChange} />
        <SearchResult data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then, inside your Search component, replace `console.log(result);` with `this.props.onDataFetched(result)`